# Rearranging an array in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have the following problem that I want to implement on CUDA:

I want to read an array (say "flag[20]"), and based on a certain condition, write indices of this array to another array (say "pindex[]")

Simple code implementation in C can be:

```
int N = 20;
int flag[N];
int pindex[N];

for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    flag[i] = -1;

for(int i=0;i<N;i+=2)
    flag[i] = 0;

for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    pindex[i] = 0;

//operation: count # of times flag != -1 and write those indices in a different array
int pcount1 = 0;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if(flag[i] != -1)
    {
        pindex[pcount1] = i;
        ++pcount1;
    }
}
```

How will I implement this in CUDA?

I can use atomicAdd() to calculate total number of times my condition is satisfied. But, how do I write indices in a different array. For example, I tried the following:

```
__global__ void kernel_tryatomic(int N,int* pcount,int* flag, int* pindex)
{
  int tId=threadIdx.x;
  int n=(blockIdx.x*2+blockIdx.y)*BlockSize+tId;

  if(n > N-1) return;    

  if(flag[n] != -1)
  {
      atomicAdd(pcount,1);
      atomicExch(&pindex[*pcount],n); 
      //pindex[*pcount] = n;
  }
}
```

This code calculates "pcount" correctly, but does not update "pindex" array.

I need help to do this operation on GPUs.

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do is called *prefix sum* or *scan*. Google these terms plus *CUDA* keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore prefix sum on cuda.

Answer (score 2):

Since your condition (`flag`) is conceptually a binary, you can use binary prefix sum (thoroughly explained [here](http://booksite.elsevier.com/samplechapters/9780123859631/Chapter_3.pdf)) to determine which place the thread with a positive flag should write.

For example if `N` is 20, with the help of below `__device__` functions:

```
__device__ int lanemask_lt(int lane) {
    return (1 << (lane)) − 1;
}

__device__ int warp_prefix_sums(int lane, int p) {
    const int mask = lanemask_lt( lane );
    int b = __ballot( p );
    return __popc( b & mask );
}
```

your `__global__` function can simply be written like below:

```
__global__ void kernel_scan(int N,int* pcount,int* flag, int* pindex)
{
    int tId=threadIdx.x;
    if(tId >= N)
        return;    
    int threadFlag = ( flag[tId] == -1 ) ? 0 : 1;
    int position_to_write = warp_prefix_sum( tId & (warpSize-1), threadFlag );
    if( threadFlag )
        pindex[ position_to_write ] = tId;  
}
```

If `N` is bigger than the warp size (32), you can use intra-block binary prefix sum that is explained in the [provided link](http://booksite.elsevier.com/samplechapters/9780123859631/Chapter_3.pdf).